# End of range in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to define a variable with the row beyond a certain range in excel vba and for some reason I keep getting an object required compiler error at the definition when I try to run it.  I am new to vba and am really confused by this error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Set endRng2 = rng2.Rows.Count + 2
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide more of your code. Please include the delcarations, as well as the minimum amount of code to allow us to interpret or debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `endRng2` is a Range object. Like you declared it as `Dim endRng2 as Range`. Unfortunately, `rng2.Rows.Count + 2` will return an Integer (namely the number of rows in rng2 + 2). You can't set a Range Object to an integer so VBA is making a fuss.

Either change the type of `endRng2` to an integer with `Dim endRng2 as Integer` or change `rng2.Rows.Count + 2` to return a Range instead of a number. For instance, if you want endRng2 to be the entire row that is 2 rows down from the last cell in `rng2` then use `Set endRng2 = rng2.Offset(0,rng2.Rows.Count+2).EntireRow` or something like that...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the declaration lines in my question but I did declare it originally as an integer and it is still giving me a compiler error.

Comment: Drop the Set keyword (only used for objects), and I suggest declaring endRng2 as Long, not Integer

Comment: Shouldn't give a compile error as an integer, but could give a runtime mismatch or overflow error...

Comment: I'm guessing that `rng2` is not an object (`Range`). It may be undeclared/unassigned.

Answer (score 0):

`rng2` may be undeclared/unassigned.

If so, you will get a 424 Object Required error.

Ensure that `rng2` is a valid Range variable.